# Making floated elements take available space

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

This has probably been asked before but I couldn't work out the right search terms to find it.

I have a whole bunch of floated elements, they look a bit like this:

[image: Identical Floated Elements] ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/YM_Industries/pen/pJpGJJ))

This is satisfying. Unfortunately I have a new requirement that means that the height of individual elements can be changed dynamically by the user.

[image: Different Floated Elements] ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/YM_Industries/pen/BNJMab))

As you can see, the elements start piling up on the right of the tall element, before eventually overflowing and leaving a gap on the left.

[image: Different Inline-block Elements] ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/YM_Industries/pen/gpoqbQ))

This is better than the floated elements, but there is still a lot of unused space. Additionally I have to carefully avoid using whitespace in the DOM between these inline elements to avoid extra spacing being added. This is very annoying.

I want it to look a bit more like this: [image: Mockup]

I'd prefer a pure-CSS solution, but I'm willing to use JavaScript if I have to.

Here's the code to produce the second image in this post in-case CodePen is inaccessible:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated height">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
  <div class="floated">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 1200px;
}

.floated {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.floated::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.height {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Can you structure it as columns?

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately I can't, the reading order of the elements has to be left-right top-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a codepen with the closest I could get with a pure CSS solution, it does involve changing the markup but leaves it in a row format:

http://codepen.io/stufu/pen/qdpvqw

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 1200px;
}
.float-row { position:relative; padding:20px 0; }
.float-row:after { content:''; display:block; clear:both; height:1px; width:1px; }

.floated {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  top:auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.floated.col1{
  left:0;
}
.floated.col2{
  left:200px;
}
.floated.col3{
  left:400px;
}
.floated.col4{
  left:600px;
}
.floated.col5{
  left:800px;
}

.floated.push { top:120px; }

.floated::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.height {
  height: 150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-row">
    <div class="floated col1"></div>
    <div class="floated col2"></div>
    <div class="floated col3"></div>
    <div class="floated col4"></div>
    <div class="floated col5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-row">
    <div class="floated col1"></div>
    <div class="floated col2"></div>
    <div class="floated height col3"></div>
    <div class="floated col4"></div>
    <div class="floated col5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-row">
    <div class="floated col1"></div>
    <div class="floated col2"></div>
    <div class="floated push col3"></div>
    <div class="floated col4"></div>
    <div class="floated col5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This isn't a great approach though, because any time height is added you have to account for it with classes that push the div down (and maybe make others to pull it). Not to mention if the heights are varying with based on dynamic content.. this would be next to impossible to maintain.

Also, I'd say if the concern was to keep this reading in a left to right format.. isn't that idea out the window as soon as a column increases in size? Either the small row in that column gets pushed down and is now read last, or you pull it to the left and it is now out of order.

I see this as needing to either be limited, tough to maintain, or you go down the [isotope path](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) which might be a little extreme.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me, as the width of my container is not fixed. On small screens I will only get one cell per row, and on large screens I may get 12 or more. So I don't actually know where the divide between the rows will be.

With regards to reading order, I really just want the top left corner of each cell to be left-right top-bottom.

I'm not sure Isotope would suit my requirements. MasonryJS achieves something close to the effect I want, but it seems like a heavy solution.